# Add variables to a combined insert and select query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a combined INSERT and SELECT in my php code and I really need it to add a few variables instead of what's in the database.

Original Code:

```
 $result2 = mysqli_query($res, "INSERT INTO editor (track,userid,title,page_title,background,video,main_heading,subtext1,subtext2,subtext3,subtext4,btncolor,btntcolor,btntsize,htsize,htcolor,onesize,onecolor,twosize,twocolor,threesize,threecolor,addvideo,formr,gotourl,visitors,precount,joincount,archive,popup) SELECT track,userid,title,page_title,background,video,main_heading,subtext1,subtext2,subtext3,subtext4,btncolor,btntcolor,btntsize,htsize,htcolor,onesize,onecolor,twosize,twocolor,threesize,threecolor,addvideo,formr,gotourl,visitors,precount,joincount,archive,popup FROM editor WHERE id='$lp' AND userid='$uplineid'");
```

Instead of it selecting the `userid` from the table, I would like it to use the variable `$myid` and instead of `track` I would like to use `$track` and for `visitors` I would like to use `$visitors`

So it would insert those variables with the rest of the database information.

I have tried everything and keep getting errors. Any help would be great.

Comment: What error(s) are you getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query like below..

```
1-$qryIns = "insert into tab1 (c1, c2, c3) select c1, '" . $_REQUEST['data'] . "', c3 from tab2;";

2-$qryIns = "insert into tab1 (c1, c2, c3) select c1, '" . $_REQUEST['data'] . "' c2, c3 from tab2;";
```